# Laravel how to set session from own table and display to view

Tags: laravel, session

I've been googling and also going through Laravel docs but didn't find the solution.

I want to set session from using table data, then display it in the view. Previously, when I used native PHP, I did this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username, full_name from tbl_user WHERE username = 'john01'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

$_SESSION['full_name'] = $row['full_name'];
?>

<?php echo $_SESSION['full_name'] ?>
```

But in Laravel, I failed. Here is my code:

Auth Controller:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Validator;
    use Session;
    use App\User;

    class Login extends Controller
    {
    public function auth(Request $r) {
       $data = [
          'username'   => $r->input('txt_username'), //my username text_field
          'password'   => $r->input('txt_password') // my password text_field
       ];

       Auth::attempt($data);
       if(Auth::check()) {

           $data2 = DB::table('tbl_user')
                ->select('user_id','username', 'full_name')
                ->where('username', '=', $data->$r->input('txt_username'))
                ->limit(1)
                ->get();

           foreach($data2 as $a) {
               Session::put('full_name', $a->full_name);
           }

           return redirect('home', ['data' => $data2]);
       }else{
           return redirect('login');
       }
   }
?>
```

If I type wrong username or password, page will redirect to "login" and cannot access "home", but when I click "login", Then I get this error:

```
TypeError
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct(): Argument #2 ($status) must be of type int, array given
```

Thank you for your suggestion and help

Comment: Do you mean that when you put the right username an password, instead of authenticating successfully, you are getting the mentioned error above?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi yes correct. if I comment out the query builder section and just type return redirect('home') after Auth, it will directly go to home. But I cannot echo session on home page. I need to set session for some field on my table (tbl_user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer:

```
    public function auth(Request $r) {

        $username = $r->input('txt_username');
        $password = $r->input('txt_password');

        $data = DB::table('tbl_user')
                ->select('user_id', 'username', 'full_name')
                ->where('username', '=', $username)
                ->limit(1)
                ->get();
        
        if(Hash::check($password, $data[0]->password)) {
            Session::put('full_name', $data[0]->full_name);
            return redirect('home');
        }else{
            return redirect('/');
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a Session in Laravel you can use this function:

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

In Your code, would be similar to

```
session(['full_name' => $a->full_name]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't get on how to grab a "full_name" value from table to session

Answer (score 0):

**Via a request instance**

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still didn't get an idea how to grab a "full_name" value from table into session